# CSS z-index and positioning issue

Tags: css, position

I'm having an issue where if I set the z-index of a parent element that is positioned relatively, then the pseudo element can't be positioned behind it.

Example: http://dabblet.com/gist/2948390

HTML:

```
<div class="img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/344"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
  background:#fff;
  z-index:10;
  position:relative;
  width:500px;
  height:344px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}

.img:after {
  content:'';
  z-index:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-5px;
  left:10px;
  width:50%;
  height:20%;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

You can see here, where if I remove the z-index from the parent element and change the z-index on the pseudo element to a negative, then it works.

http://dabblet.com/gist/2948402

Unfortunately, I can't use that method because of how things are being positioned on the rest of the page. I have to be able to set a z-index on the parent element.

Any idea why my first example is functioning like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even elements with negative `z-index` will always be in front of the border/background of the containing element if the containing element establishes a stacking context. Every item that has a `z-index` value that isn't `auto` forms a stacking context:

> **`'z-index'`**
>
> ```
>     Value:   auto | <integer> | inherit
>   Initial:   auto 
>      [...]
> ```
>
> Values have the following meanings:
>
> **`<integer>`**
>       This integer is the stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context. The box also establishes a new stacking context.
>
> **`auto`**
>       The stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is 0. The box does not establish a new stacking context unless it is the root element.
>
> [...]
>
> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. [...]

That's why your second version works, the `.img` wont create a new stacking context.

See [CSS 2.1: 9.9.1 Specifying the stack level: the 'z-index' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)) for more information.

#### Solution

Don't forget that you can create a second pseudo-element, `.img:before`. Scale it to the maximum, set its `z-index` to a negative value higher than `.img:after` and add a `background-color`. Since it will be rendered on top of `.img:after` it will create the effect of `.img:after` being positioned behind `.img`:

```
.img {
    background:#fff;
    z-index:10;
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:344px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}

.img:before{ /* create a pseudo-background */
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#fff;
    content: '';
}

.img:after {
    content:'';
    z-index:-2;  /* lower value than .img:before{z-index} */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-5px;
    left:10px;
    width:50%;
    height:20%;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

[**dabblet demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/2948884)